# No puedo obtener los datos con métodod get() de una StringVar

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Cuando intento ingresar datos para guardarlos en la base de datos, en la tupla están vacíos los datos.

Este es mi código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
import socios

#------------------------------Pantalla Principal-----------------------------------------

class FormularioSocios:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socio1 = socios.Socios()
        self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title('Administración de Socios')
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
        self.carga_socios()
        self.consulta_por_dni()
        self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row =0, padx =10, pady = 10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def carga_socios(self):
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text = 'Carga de Socios')

        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text = 'Socios')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row= 0, padx = 5, pady = 10)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dni:')
        self.label1.grid(column =0, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.dnicarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydni = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.dnicarga)
        self.entrydni.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Nombre:')
        self.label2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.nombrecarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrynombre = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.nombrecarga)
        self.entrynombre.grid(column = 1, row =1, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Apellido:')
        self.label3.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.apellidocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryapellido = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.apellidocarga)
        self.entryapellido.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Sexo:')
        self.label4.grid(column = 0, row =3, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.sexocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrysexo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.sexocarga)
        self.entrysexo.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Fecha de Nacimiento:')
        self.label5.grid(column = 0, row =4, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.fechacarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryfecha = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.fechacarga)
        self.entryfecha.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label6 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dirección:')
        self.label6.grid(column = 0, row =5, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.direccioncarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydireccion = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.direccioncarga)
        self.entrydireccion.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label7 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Plan:')
        self.label7.grid(column = 0, row =6, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.plancarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryplan = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.plancarga)
        self.entryplan.grid(column = 1, row = 6, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label8 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label8.grid(column = 0, row =7, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 7, padx = 4, pady = 4)



        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Confirmar", command=self.agregar)
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)

    def agregar(self):
        datos = (self.dnicarga.get(), self.nombrecarga.get(), self.apellidocarga.get(), self.sexocarga.get(), self.fechacarga.get(), self.direccioncarga.get(), self.plancarga.get
        (), self.telefonocarga.get())
        datos2 = (self.telefonocarga.get())
        print(datos2)
        self.socio1.alta(datos)
        mb.showinfo('Información', 'Los datos fueron cargados')
        print(datos)

    def consulta_por_dni(self):
        self.pagina2 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina2, text ='Consulta por Dni')
        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina2, text = 'Socio')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 5, pady =10)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dni:')
        self.label1.grid(column =0, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.dnicarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydni = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.dnicarga)
        self.entrydni.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Nombre:')
        self.label2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.nombrecarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrynombre = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.nombrecarga)
        self.entrynombre.grid(column = 1, row =1, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Apellido:')
        self.label3.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.apellidocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryapellido = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.apellidocarga)
        self.entryapellido.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Sexo:')
        self.label4.grid(column = 0, row =3, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.sexocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrysexo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.sexocarga)
        self.entrysexo.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Fecha de Nacimiento:')
        self.label5.grid(column = 0, row =4, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.fechacarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryfecha = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.fechacarga)
        self.entryfecha.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label6 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dirección:')
        self.label6.grid(column = 0, row =5, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.direccioncarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydireccion = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.direccioncarga)
        self.entrydireccion.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label7 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Plan:')
        self.label7.grid(column = 0, row =6, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.plancarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryplan = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.plancarga)
        self.entryplan.grid(column = 1, row = 6, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label8 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label8.grid(column = 0, row =7, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 7, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label9 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label9.grid(column = 0, row =8, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 8, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text = 'Consultar', command = self.consultar)
        self.boton1.grid(column = 1, row = 8, padx = 4, pady = 4)

    def consultar(self):
        datos = (self.dnicarga.get(),)
        respuesta=self.socio1.consulta(datos)
        if len(respuesta)>0:
            self.dnicarga.set(respuesta[0][0])
            self.nombrecarga.set(respuesta[0][1])
        else:
            self.dnicarga.set('')
            self.nombrecarga.set('')
            mb.showinfo("Información", "No existe un artículo con dicho código")

    def listado_completo(self):
        self.pagina3 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina3, text = 'Listado Completo')
        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina3, text = 'Socios')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx =5, pady = 10)
        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text = 'Listado completo', command = self.listar)
        self.boton1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx =4, pady =4)
        self.scrolledtext1 = st.ScrolledText(self.labelframe1, width = 30, height = 10)
        self.scrolledtext1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx =10, pady = 10)

    def listar(self):
        respuesta = self.socio1.recuperar_todos()
        self.scrolledtext1.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        for fila in respuesta:
            self.scrolledtext1.insert(tk.END,"código:"+str(fila[0])+"\ndni:"+fila[1]+"\nnombre:"+str(fila[2])+"\n\n")

aplicacion1 = FormularioSocios()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que **estás usando los mismos atributos para asignar las instancias de los widgets y de las `StringVars` en el formulario de la pestaña de carga y en el de consulta`**. Esto hace que lo que te retorna desde la pestaña de carga es el contenido de los entries de la pestaña de consulta, que están vacíos.

Bastaría con renombrar los atributos de clase que defines en `consulta_por_dni` para que no se reasignen nuevos objetos a los definidos en `carga_socios`, por ejemplo pasando `self.dnicarga` a `self.dniconsulta` y así con el resto.

No obstante, considera usar algunas clases adicionales que se encarguen de definir los formularios de cada pestaña, de esta forma separas el código y puedes reutilizarlo. Aparentemente tanto la pestaña de carga como la de consulta tiene el mismo formulario, no tiene sentido que escribas dos veces el mismo código cuando puedes usar una clase e instanciar las veces que quieras. Podría quedar algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st

import socios



class SocioForm(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Socios')
        self.labelframe.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.label_dni = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Dni:')
        self.label_dni.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.dni = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_dni = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.dni)
        self.entry_dni.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_nombre = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Nombre:')
        self.label_nombre.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.nombre = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_nombre = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.nombre)
        self.entry_nombre.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_apellido = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Apellido:')
        self.label_apellido.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.apellido = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_apellido = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.apellido)
        self.entry_apellido.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_sexo = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Sexo:')
        self.label_sexo.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.sexo = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_sexo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.sexo)
        self.entry_sexo.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_fecha = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Fecha de Nacimiento:')
        self.label_fecha.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.fecha = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_fecha = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.fecha)
        self.entry_fecha.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_direccion = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text = 'Dirección:')
        self.label_direccion.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.direccion = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_direccion = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.direccion)
        self.entry_direccion.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_plan = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Plan:')
        self.label_plan.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.plan = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_plan = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.plan)
        self.entry_plan.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label_telefono = ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text='Telefono:')
        self.label_telefono.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.telefono = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_telefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.telefono)
        self.entry_telefono.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.boton_aceptar = ttk.Button(self.labelframe, text="Aceptar")
        self.boton_aceptar.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)


    def get_data(self):
        datos = (self.dni.get(), self.nombre.get(),
                 self.apellido.get(), self.sexo.get(),
                 self.fecha.get(), self.direccion.get(),
                 self.plan.get(), self.telefono.get()
                 )

        return datos


class Listado(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Socios')
        self.labelframe.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.boton = ttk.Button(self.labelframe,
                                text='Listado completo')
        self.boton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.scrolledtext = st.ScrolledText(self.labelframe, width=30, height=10)
        self.scrolledtext.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class FormularioSocios(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.socio = Socios()

        self.carga_form = SocioForm(self)
        self.add(self.carga_form, text='Carga de Socios')
        self.carga_form.boton_aceptar.config(command=self.agregar,
                                             text="Cargar")

        self.consulta_form = SocioForm(self)
        self.add(self.consulta_form, text='Consulta por Dni')
        self.consulta_form.boton_aceptar.config(command=self.consultar,
                                                text="Consultar")

        self.listado = Listado(self)
        self.add(self.listado, text='Listado Completo')
        self.listado.boton.config(command=self.listar)


    def agregar(self):
        datos = self.carga_form.get_data()
        self.socio.alta(datos)
        mb.showinfo('Información', 'Los datos fueron cargados')
        print(datos)


    def consultar(self):
        datos = self.consulta_form.get_data()
        respuesta = self.socio.consulta(datos)
        if len(respuesta) > 0:
            self.consulta_form.dni.set(respuesta[0][0])
            self.consulta_form.set.set(respuesta[0][1])
        else:
            self.consulta_form.dni.set('')
            self.consulta_form.nombre.set('')
            mb.showinfo("Información", "No existe un artículo con dicho código")

    def listar(self):
        respuesta = self.socio.recuperar_todos()
        self.listado.scrolledtext.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        for fila in respuesta:
            text =  f"código: {fila[0]}\ndni: {fila[1]}\nnombre: {fila[2]}\n\n"
            self.listado.scrolledtext.insert(tk.END, text)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    form = FormularioSocios(root)
    form.grid(column=0, row =0, padx =10, pady = 10)
    root.mainloop()
```